# What happens if we give a command to LCD to print something without clearing the initial data it is displaying? Does it overwrite the previous data?

Tags: arduino, embedded, lcd

I've just started with embedded systems. Although, lcd should be cleared to print new values, but I read a code which was working even without clearing lcd.

EDIT: The LCD is based on JHD162A

Comment: This would entirely depend on the LCD's unspecified controller.  To get help here, your question must specify all of the information required for someone to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please indicate display controller type, a popular one is the [HD44780](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller) which is compatible with a JHD162J.

Some displays can be set to scroll text, or wrap around an internal frame buffer, on small displays the frame buffer may not be fully displayed and your new text may be hidden. Setting the **cursor to home** and **resetting the data** address are recommended if you want to recover from display overflows in practice without clearing the display, however clearing the display is not required if you update fast you cannot even see the blank interval just write enough spaces to clear the rest of the display from what was there before.

Answer (score 1):

On a character display, you have to specify where to start printing.  If there is already text starting there, it will be replaced by your new text.  If the new text is shorter than the old text, the end of the old text will remain.